# PHP get is missing parameters?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, get, postman

I'm trying to get the value of a column (the column name entered as a parameter) given a username (entered as second parameter). Below is my code and postman. The postman output is saying that I have missing parameters?

```
$app->get('/getInformation', function(Request $request, Response $response){

if(!haveEmptyParameters(array('field', 'username'), $request, $response)){
    $request_data = $request->getParsedBody(); 
    $field = $request_data['field'];
    $username = $request_data['username'];

    $db = new DbOperations; 
    $result = $db->getInformation($field,$username);

    $response_data = array();
    $response_data['error'] = false; 
    $response_data['users'] = $result; 

    $response->write(json_encode($response_data));

    return $response
    ->withHeader('Content-type', 'application/json')
    ->withStatus(200);  
}

});
```

haveemptyparameters function:

```
    function haveEmptyParameters($required_params, $request, $response){
    $error = false; 
    $error_params = '';
    $request_params = $request->getParsedBody(); 

    foreach($required_params as $param){
        if(!isset($request_params[$param]) || strlen($request_params[$param])<=0){
            $error = true; 
            $error_params .= $param . ', ';
        }
    }

    if($error){
        $error_detail = array();
        $error_detail['error'] = true; 
        $error_detail['message'] = 'Required parameters ' . substr($error_params, 0, -2) . ' are missing or empty';
        $response->write(json_encode($error_detail));
    }
    return $error; 
}

$app->run();
```

getInformation, as called in the get. I'm pretty sure this part works.

```
public function getInformation($field, $username) {

        $query ="select $field from registeruser where username=?";
        $stmt = $this->con->prepare($query);
        $stmt->bind_param("s",$username);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($result);
        $stmt->fetch();
        return $result;
    }
```

And the postman input+output is below, screenshotted.

[Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rQomw.png)

Comment: What framework are you using?

Comment: I think it's Slim 3.